# How to measure distance between two elements in a web page

Tags: data-mining, internet

Suppose we want to measure how closely relevant is one word or phrase to another in a webpage, this can be easily seen by eyes whether they are near. But in an HTML document it could be tricky to calculate, because those words could belong to different elements and HTML document has the tree structure, hence it's not accurate to depend on counting text distance in HTML source.

Is there already an algorithms or formula exist for this?

Comment: Why process HTML code and not the actual text?

Comment: I think because for the particular case, the structure of the HTML element is important.

Comment: I will try to parse the HTML document and remove usual codes for references, italics, bolds, etc using regular expressions (and also get rid of menus and all the other stuff except the body of the document). After that, you can do your analysis on the cleaned text.